# Why does fstab sometimes not work?

Tags: macos, startup, automount

I have several boot drives in my Mac Pro, each with different operating systems.  Right now, I have Sierra, Yosemite, and Windows 10.  I use `vifs` to edit the fstab file, to prevent other volumes from mounting automatically at boot.  But under Sierra, this is sometimes ignored, and the other two volumes are mounted automatically at boot.  I never have this problem under Yosemite.  The strange thing is, it doesn't happen every time.  Sometimes when I boot Sierra, the other two volumes are mounted, and sometimes they are not.  Below is the contents of my fstab from Sierra.

```
#
# Warning - this file should only be modified with vifs(8)
#
# Failure to do so is unsupported and may be destructive.
#
#Windows
UUID=0EC23A58-2503-48E4-88FB-3F13F1F80F6A       none    ntfs    ro,noauto
#
#yosemite
UUID=66A393D3-C723-42D6-89A3-EA68B961FFF3       none    hfs     rw,noauto
```